# How do I add a loop when using R to scrape data?

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a database of crime data by zip code based on Trulia.com's data. I have the code below but so far it only produces 1 line of data. In the code below, Zipcodes is just a list of US zip codes. Can anyone tell me what I need to add to make this run through my entire list "i" ?

Here is a link to one of the Trulia pages for reference: https://www.trulia.com/real_estate/20004-Washington/crime/

UPDATE:
Here are zip codes for download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxukqpu0v88d7tf/Zip%20Code%20Database%20wo%20Boston.xlsx?dl=0

I also changed the code a bit this time after realizing the crime stats appear in different orders depending on the zip code. Is it possible to have the loop produce 4 lines per zipcode? This currently works but only produces the last zip code in the dataset. I can't figure out how to make sure each zip code's data is recorded on separate lines, so it doesn't overwrite and only leave one line of the last zip code.

Please help!!

```
 library(rvest)

 data=data.frame(Zipcodes)
 for(i in data$Zip.Code)
 {  
 site <- paste("https://www.trulia.com/real_estate/",i,"-Boston/crime/", sep="")
 site <- html(site)

 crime<- data.frame(zip =i,
        type =site %>% html_nodes(".brs") %>% html_text() ,
        stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
View(crime)
```

If that code doesn't work, try this:

```
data=data.frame(Zillow_Data_for_R_Test)
for(i in data$Zip.Code)
site <- paste("https://www.trulia.com/real_estate/",i,"-Boston/crime/", sep="")
site <- read_html(site)
crime<- data.frame(zip =i,
         theft =site %>% html_nodes(".crime-text-0") %>% html_text() ,
         assault =site %>% html_nodes(".crime-text-1") %>% html_text() ,
         arrest =site %>% html_nodes(".crime-text-2") %>% html_text() ,
         vandalism =site %>% html_nodes(".crime-text-3") %>% html_text() ,
         robbery =site %>% html_nodes(".crime-text-4") %>% html_text() ,
         type =site %>% html_nodes(".clearfix") %>% html_text() ,
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
View(crime)
```

Comment: It will be difficult to answer your question without including some example data (i.e., `Zipcodes`). For the record though your for loop shouldn't work as the code after `for(i in data$Zip.Code)` should be enclosed in curly brackets; and even if this did work your `crime` object would just be overwritten at each iteration.

Comment: This would be a great time to consider using `ret <- lapply(data$Zip.Code, function(zc) { ... })`, capturing all data.frames into a list, then `do.call(rbind, ret)`. It would require the least amount of change to your current methodology (assuming it is working correctly for each zipcode).

Comment: @jruf003 I have added the database of zip codes I'm working with and I also added the brackets you suggested. How do I fix it so the crime object isn't overwritten at each iteration?

Comment: For a fully reproducible example you should add something like `head(Zipcodes)` so that we know what your zip codes actually are. Regarding your loop, @r2evans has already provided an answer how to avoid overwriting. It uses `lapply` instead of a for loop. `lapply` is more efficient in your case and also more elegant R code. The less efficient/elegant way would be to initialize an empty `data.frame` crime with a number of rows equaling the number of zipcodes and then do an assignment resembling `crime[i,] <- scrapeddata` in your for loop.

Comment: Hi @ManuelBickel Thank you for your response, I do not know how to use the lapply function... What is the code I would write for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of @r2evans already provides an answer. Since the @ShanCham asked how to actually implement this I wanted to guide with the following code, which is just more verbose than the comment and could therefore not be posted as additional comment.

```
library(rvest)

#only two exemplary zipcodes, could be more, of course
zipcodes <- c("02110", "02125")

crime <- lapply(zipcodes, function(z) {

  site <- read_html(paste0("https://www.trulia.com/real_estate/",z,"-Boston/crime/"))

           #for illustrative purposes:
           #introduced as.numeric to numeric columns
           #exluded some of your other columns and shortenend the current text in type
           data.frame(zip = z,
                      theft = site %>% html_nodes(".crime-text-0") %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric(),
                      assault = site %>% html_nodes(".crime-text-1") %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric() ,
                      type = site %>% html_nodes(".clearfix") %>% html_text() %>% paste(collapse = " ") %>% substr(1, 50) ,
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})

class(crime)
#list

#Output are lists that can be bound together to one data.frame
crime <- do.call(rbind, crime)

#crime is a data.frame, hence, classes/types are kept
class(crime$type)
# [1] "character"
class(crime$assault)
# [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I think the `i` in `site <- read_html(paste0("https://www.trulia.com/real_estate/",i,"-Boston/crime/"))` should be replaced with a `z`

Comment: You are right, sorry for the typo and thanks for highlighting it, I forgot to change that when copying parts of the code. I have corrected it in my answer now.